# Visual Studio 2015/17 Startup times

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am wondering what i can do to avoid long startup times for my Development environments as both 2015 and 2017
of Microsoft visual Studio seem to search for all installed Assembly's and as i have several tool kits installed this takes 
a very long time. I have Telrik as well as Infragistics and some other smaller tools. I googled but could not find any specific hint.

Comment: My first advice is if you don't have an SSD get one. Although with that said your problem appears to be .net related and I don't use that at all. I am a native c++ developer.

Comment: SSD, faster CPU,  maybe some more RAM if you have less than 16 GB.

Comment: Check VS2017 `Help -> Manage Visual Studio Perfomance` to find extentions which can slow down startup.

Comment: I doubt it is my CPU nor the mem or HD, i have 128GB Mem, Dual Intel Xeon and all SSD's so you can rule out the Hardware. Problem seems to be that i have like multiple version of tools installed and that makes this worse. Wish there would be a way that you can load Visual studio withut tool and then only load the ones you want on a per project basis,. But for now i have not found that option